# addEventListener calling function twice with in immediate function pattern

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am getting issue with calling immediate function with addEventListener, which is calling it twice. tried to change from bubbling to capturing but not working.
here is my code

some description: I am trying to add text box where it clicked.

```
var mod = (function(){

    var sEventType = 'click',
        labelObj = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

            return {

                    createTextBox : function(targetId,inputVal){

                        alert('hi');
                        var elemInput = document.createElement('input');
                    },

                    addEvents : function(){

                        for (var i = 0; i < labelObj.length; i++) {
                            if (window.addEventListener) //Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 10
                            labelObj[i].addEventListener(sEventType,function(){ mod.createTextBox(this,this.innerHTML);}, false);
                            else if (window.attachEvent) //IE < 9
                            labelObj[i].attachEvent(sEventType, function(){ mod.createTextBox(this,this.innerHTML);});
                        }
                    }
          }
  }());

  //Intialise Event
  mod.addEvents();
```

Check out addEventListener which is calling createTextBox ,alert inside popup twice.

Here is HTML part

```
<body>

<div id='tableMain'>

  <div id='exlTopHd'>
    <div id='loginData'>
      <div id='yourName'><label id='mNam'>type your name here</label></div>
      <div id='yourEmail'><label>your email address</label></div>
    </div>
    <div id='exlCtr'>
        <div id='exlTitle'><label>add title<lable></div>
        <div id='addRow'>+row</div>
        <div id='addColomn'>+colomn</div>
        <div id='saveExl'>saving...</div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div id='exlTb'></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not related, but for legacy IE snippet you need `'on' + sEventType...`.

Comment: what is the value of `labelObj.length`

Comment: labelObj.length value is 3.

Comment: After creating an `input` element, you will append it to `label`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you've nested an `input` within `label` like this:

```
<label>Check 1: <input type="checkbox" /></label>
```

Clicking on a `label` triggers also a click on `input`, when using nested elements. To avoid this you can use `for` attribute:

```
<label for="check1">Check 1: </label><input id="check1" type="checkbox" />
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZNZz/).

---

**EDIT**

Looks like you edited your question at the same time I wrote my answer. Anyway, what's written above, stands, even if the `input`s would be added dynamically. Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZNZz/2/), and let me know, if that's what you need. The snippet creates `input`s dynamically, and inserts them after `label`.

Here's the modified code snippet:

```
var mod = (function () {
    var sEventType = 'click',
        labelObj = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    return {
        createTextBox: function (e) {
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
                parent = target.parentElement,
                elemInput = document.createElement('input');
                inpId = parent.id + 'Inp';
            elemInput.value = target.innerHTML;
            elemInput.id = inpId;
            target.setAttribute('for', inpId);
            parent.insertBefore(elemInput, target.nextSibling);
        },
        addEvents: function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < labelObj.length; i++) {
                if (window.addEventListener) //Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 10
                labelObj[i].addEventListener(sEventType, function (e) {
                    mod.createTextBox(e);
                }, false);
                else if (window.attachEvent) //IE < 9
                labelObj[i].attachEvent('on' + sEventType, function (e) {
                    mod.createTextBox(e);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}());
```